# Moving commits from one branch to another

Tags: git, merge, branch, rebase

I've committed a bunch of changes onto the master branch of my git repository, and pushed it upstream (although I'm the only one working out of these.)  What I want to do is to pull these last few commits off, roll back master to before the pulled-off commits, re-apply the commits onto the develop branch, and then merge back onto master.

Here's what my repository looks like now:

```
a [master] [remotes/origin/master]
|
b
|
c
|
d (merge branch 'develop')
|\
| \
|  e [develop] [remotes/origin/develop]
|  |
q  f
|  |
r  g
```

And here's what I want it to look like:

```
Z [master] [remotes/origin/master]
|\
| \
|  A
|  |
|  B
|  |
d  C
|\ |
| \|
|  e [develop] [remotes/origin/develop]
|  |
q  f
|  |
r  g
```

Can I get some help on this?  I'm thinking this is a job for rebase, but I'm not quite sure how to make it happen.

Comment: Your diagrams confused me for a bit - in the future, you might want to label your commits in chronological order instead of reverse.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here you are:

```
# move cba onto e
git branch foo
git rebase --onto <SHA1-e> <SHA1-d> foo

# rewind master to d
git checkout master
git reset --hard <SHA1-d>

# merge
git merge foo
```

You might want to pick a more descriptive branch name than foo, since it'll be recorded in the merge commit message for Z.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.  I was getting part-way there, but the reset was what I was missing.